# What exactly Peak Concurrent User means

Tags: sql, analytics

what exactly PCU refer?
I have data like this can anyone tell me from this data what would be the result for peak concurrent users?
How to calculate PCU using sql query according to this data?
[image]

Comment: What database and version are you using? This is easy to solve in Microsoft Sql Server, PostgreSQL, MySQL 8+, etc, but messy to solve in MySQL 5.6, for example...

Comment: Self join, group by.

Comment: regarding SQL query, show us what you have tried already

Comment: @Dharanesh . . . Are you sure the data is perfectly interleaved so there aren't two logins or logouts in a row for the same user.

Answer (score 1):

PCU would mean the maximum number of users logged in **at the same time** during a given time period.

In your data you only have two users, so it can never be more than 2.  We can see that at times, both users are logged in at the same time, so PCU=2 for this data.

Comment: Thanks for reply. PCU =2 means user_id 1 login at 13:37 and 2 login at 13:45 in between 13:37 to 13:45 user_id 1 not logged out so PCU =2 right.

Comment: @Dharanesh Yes. To find the peak you look across the entire time period to find the maximum number of users that are logged in at the same time.

Comment: Can you to tell me how to get this result using mysql query

Comment: @Dharanesh Do you need to do it in mysql? It would be a lot easier to do this in a language that allows a looping structure? The only way to do that in MySql I think is with a cursor https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cursor/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have access to Window Functions / Analytic Functions...

```
SELECT
    MAX(concurrent_users)   AS peak_concurrent_users
FROM
(
    SELECT
        SUM(CASE WHEN event = 'logout' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END)
            OVER (ORDER BY __time, user_id, event)
                AS concurrent_users
    FROM
        yourTable
    WHERE
        event IN ('login', 'logout')
)
    AS running_total
```

This just adds up how many people have logged in or out in time order, and keeps a running total. When someone logs in, the number goes up, when someone logs out, the number goes down.

Where two events happen at exactly the same time, it assumes the lowest user_id actually went first. And if a user has a login and logout at exactly the same time, it assumes the login actually went first.

Comment: Thanks, Actually i am using Apache druid it will support mysql queries but it doesn't support window function(OVER, LAG, LEAD...)

Comment: @Dharanesh . . . This is using standard SQL and your question has not specified the database you are using.  This is the correct answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff . . . I think this query gives Active CCU not a peak ccu

Comment: @Dharanesh . . . This gives the maximum value, which certainly seems like "peak" to me.  If that is not what you mean, then your question is not clear.